# How to link c++ to OpenBlas?

Tags: c++, linker, static-linking, openblas

I installed OpenBlas and could compile C programs linked to OpenBlas by using

```
 gcc testOpenBlas.c  -I /opt/OpenBLAS/include/ -L/opt/OpenBLAS/lib -lopenblas
```

If I try to link c++ programs using g++ and the same linker options I get the error:

```
testOpenBlas.cpp:1:28: fatal error: OpenBlas/cblas.h: No such file or directory
 #include <OpenBlas/cblas.h>
```

Any hints?

Comment: this is not a linker error

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did:
I had to recompile OpenBlas again with g++.
I found that the common.h file exists in the source folder, so I had to include it instead of the installation folder '/opt/OpenBlas'. I still use '-L/opt/OpenBLAS/lib' flag.

Then the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

This include directive is looking for the path `OpenBlas/cblas.h` in all your include directories, in particular also in `/opt/OpenBLAS/include/`.

So the question is: does there exist a file `/opt/OpenBLAS/include/OpenBlas/cblas.h`?

Also I think you might have to specify the `-I` flag before the source file.

Comment: `/opt/OpenBLAS/include/cblas.h`  exists. In my code, I have also `#include <OpenBlas/common.h> `. common.h is not in the include folder however.

Comment: I found that the source file should be typed before the -I flag.